# One side angled rectangle in android xml

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to draw one sided angled rectangle in android xml. Like this image below...

[image]

Comment: do not use xml for that, it is pointless, instead use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class

Comment: Forgive me, but that shape doesn't appear on my screen as a rectangle, it appears as a quadrilateral in which two of the sides are parallel and two of the angles are right angles.

Answer (score 3):

Can be achieved using the following xml code. only downside is that the second rectangle should match the color of background.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <!-- Colored rectangle-->
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="100dp"
                    android:height="40dp" />
                <solid android:color="#F00" />
            </shape>
        </item>

<!-- Overlay with same color as background-->
    <item
        android:top="20dp"
        android:bottom="-40dp"
        android:right="-30dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-60">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```